# version property dynamic in pom.xml

Tags: maven, jenkins, github, pom.xml, nexus

I have a Maven pom.xml, I build project and executable jar deploy in Nexus with Jenkins.
But I want changes of version name according to branch name.

For example: I have in pom.xml

```
<groupId>net.test</groupId>
<artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>iin-parent</name>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

I need set like this : (Branch- Master/Test1/Test2/..)

```
<groupId>net.test</groupId>
<artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
<version>BranchName_0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>iin-parent</name>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

How can this be done?

I was using MVN build like -Drevision=BranchName-SNAPSHOT clean compile package deploy. But I want dynamically fetch the branch name.

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 10):

If you use `clean compile package deploy` you are duplicating several parts..only `clean deploy` is needed. Please read the documentation about [Maven Life cycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

Furthermore if you like to change the version dynamically you can do that by using the correct properties ([Starting with Maven 3.5.0+](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html)) which are `${revision}`, `${sha1}` and `${changelist}` so for example:

```
<groupId>net.test</groupId>
<artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>

<properties>
  <revision>1.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
</properties>
```

This can be done in Maven like this:

```
mvn -Drevision=2.0-SNAPSHOT clean package
```

or if you like to do this for a branch:

```
mvn -Drevision=2.0-BranchName-SNAPSHOT clean package
```

You have to be aware if you like to do `mvn clean deploy` please read carefully the docs and follow them.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks mvn clean deploy working fine for me.
But I have one more query : Updated pom.xml as below
<groupId>net.test</groupId>
 <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
 <version>${revision}</version>
 <name>iin-test</name>
 <packaging>pom</packaging>
 <properties>
  <revision>1.0-${git_branch}-SNAPSHOT</revision> </properties> . But not able to fetch branch name, Nexus repository saving as 1.0-$%7BGIT_BRANCH%7D-SNAPSHOT. Could you please suggest ?

Comment: you have to use one of the listed properties. You are using `revision` so you can either `sha1` and/or `changelist`. In this case I would suggest to use `sha1` as property...Apart from that what will happen if you have no branch? Or would you always make the branch being part of the version ? Something like `1.0-master` ? BTW: It better to update the post instead of giving code etc into comments which is really hard to read...

Comment: Yes I always wanted to make the naming as 1.0-branch-snapshot (where branch = master/dev/prod etc).

Comment: Sir, And what if we need to set dynamic description such different company name. basically I'm moving app to support Multi tenant, so I need to set the description based on value pass from the url. i.e if we have dsa.medium.com so I want to set dsa in pom.xml description